# What is the effectiveness of multithreaded alpha-beta-pruning?

Tags: multithreading, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

What would the effectiveness be of multithreading with alpha beta pruning if:

The multithreading was used iteratively.  For example, thread one would look at the first branch, the second thread would look at the second thread, etc.  I believe this should only be done at the first depth (the next move the AI made), since the other depths could be cut off.

One thread was at the first "move" generated searching to half the moveset generated, and the second thread was at the last "move" generated and searching back to half the moveset.  Here, I think there could be increased speedup, because the last move could be considered the best move, and as a result, the second thread could cause cutoffs the first thread couldn't.

The multithreading was used to think on the opponent's time.  For example, say the opponent took some time to think and make a move.  The AI could iteratively deepen its search and find results while the opponent is thinking, i'd imagine, not necessarily causing speedup, but having more time for minimax analysis.

There may be other optimizations, i'd imagine, but these were the few that came into mind.  I don't know if they actually will improve anything, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your idea correctly, you plan to search moves in the root position in parallel. In comparison to a strictly sequential algorithm, it should be better but I would not expect it to scale well (with multiple CPUs).

For comparison, here is a summary of existing parallelization strategies in chess:

- https://www.chessprogramming.org/Parallel_Search

As alpha-beta is a sequential algorithm, all parallelization strategies are speculative. So, you want to avoid spending time on searching parts of the search tree, which will eventually be cut by other moves. One relatively simple strategy to avoid searching irrelevant subtrees is called [Young Brothers Wait Concept](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Young_Brothers_Wait_Concept).

There are also algorithms with improved scalability but at the cost of being more difficult to understand and implement. For instance, supporting [work-stealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_stealing) should improve scalability.